# Java all methods work for a string except returning the string

Tags: java, string

for some reason, I can do just about any method for a string. This includes:

*Getting the length of the string

*Adding to the string

*Using substring

*And probably everythng else

Except, I cant get the value of the string except when using my `drawString` method to draw to the screen in lwjgl. Here is my code before i further explain the problem.

```
public static boolean chatOn = false;
public static String text = "";
public static float typetimer = 0;
public static int ctrltimer = 0;
public static boolean runcmd = false;

public static void chat() {
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_TAB)) {
        if (ctrltimer < 0) {
            chatOn = !chatOn;
            Keyboard.destroy();
            try {Keyboard.create();} catch (LWJGLException e) {}
            ctrltimer = 10;
        }
    }
    ctrltimer -= Game.delta;
    typetimer -= Game.delta;
    if (chatOn) {
        //try {text.replace(null, "happy");} catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        System.out.println(text);//print to console, dosen't
        Text.drawString(text, 0, 0);//write the text on the screen with my draw method, does work
        System.out.println(text);//print to console, dosen't, yet the one drawstring worked
        if (typetimer < 0) {
            while (Keyboard.next()) {
            try {
                    if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_BACK) {
                        text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1);
                        typetimer = 1;
                        System.out.println(text);//print to console, doesn't
                    }
                    else if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_RETURN) {
                        System.out.println(text);//print to console, doesn't
                        runCommand();
                        text = "";
                        chatOn = false;
                    } 
                    else {
                        System.out.println(text);//print to console, doesn't
                        text = text + Keyboard.getEventCharacter();
                    }
                    typetimer = 10;
            } catch(Exception e){

            }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void runCommand() {
    String command = text;
    System.out.println(command);//print to console, doesnt
    if (command.startsWith("time")) {
        try {
        String[] time = new String[1];
        time = command.split(" ", 0);
        Camera.nighttimeASecond = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not set time");
        }
    }
}
```

If you read my notes inside the code you can see where I have put `print` methods and `drawString` method. The `print` methods print nothing and sometimes might print the first few words of the string, although the `drawString` method worked fine. Thanks - Tyler

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what's actually going on?

Comment: yes i have been trying to debug it for awhile now. do you have any tricks to help debug it?

Comment: I meant setting a breakpoint, halting the execution, checking what's the content of the variable when it goes to print and what's the case in the `drawString` method. Obviously the value of the variable cannot just magically change on its own, so there must be something affecting it.

Comment: i used to get null values for the key presses. i did something and they magically disappeared. also if you look, i executed the print before and after the drawString method so thats not whats affecting it.

Comment: i created a method `getText` that returns the value of `text` and that doesn't work...

Comment: So, you're saying that `drawString` is drawing some text on the screen, when you pass an empty `String` to it? Or that `System.out.prinln()` is failing to print a `String` that does have a value? If you put in some static text, like `System.out.println("Hello world, my text is: " + text);` does that show up? What about when you pass the same thing to `drawString` in the following line?

Comment: i have an idea. the drawstring strips apart the string by using, you guessed it, methods! i would guess i could possibly get it to work like that

Answer (score 0):

If `System.out.println(text);` is empty before `Text.drawString(text, 0, 0);` is called, then `text` should be empty when `Text.drawString()` is called. You should [follow mattias' suggested debugging guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and find out where your issue is occuring (or add some `System.out.println()`s following `text` through your code and tracing it if you're particularly lazy :p). Without having a look at your `Text` class, I'd be willing to bet that the string to be printed is never getting set, and `Text` is printing a static string, or that the string to be printed is getting changed by the `Text` class itself.

Judging by:

```
String command = text;
System.out.println(command);//print to console, doesnt
```

`text` is never getting set.

Comment: I would rather recommend proper [debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)  over println. Why? Because it simply forces you to understand what is happening during execution of your code.